# replace a partial substring in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to find a certain pattern in notepad++ and delete all of it. So the lines might be something like:

```
1,2,c(0,9,3),5,7,9,2
2,3,c(4,7,2),5,4,3,1
```

and I want to get back:

```
1,2,5,7,9,2
2,3,5,4,3,1
```

how should I do this?
Thanks

Comment: 1. Please include your current regex 2. What is the pattern? You want to strip out `,c(` something `)` ? Can there also be other letters than `c` ? ...

Comment: It is specifically ,c( something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the replace dialog
2. Select the radio button for regular expressions
3. Use the search pattern

```
^(.*?),c\(.*?\)(.*?$)
```

4. Replace it by

```
$1$2
```

This should match your lines and the both capture groups capture the parts you want to keep. Then we replace by the content of the both capture groups $1$2

Comment: for some reason your code goes all the way to the end of the line and does stop at the next ")"  I found this solution, instead (?<=This is)(.*)(?=sentence). although this does not include the c( or ) just the stuff in between

Comment: My pattern is based on the 2 lines you provided. If the actual data is different, then the pattern would be different as well. The $ at the end of the pattern marks the end of the line. Feel free to experiment with it until it matches your actual data.

Comment: @seb I think she wants to get `1,2,5` and not `1,2,3` (slipped over myself almost). So if I understood right, the `,c(1,2,3)` should be removed but unclear from what criteria. At least to me.

Comment: Oh, wow, what an oversight. My answer is totally wrong. Good catch, bobble bubble.

Comment: Changed my solution.

Comment: Yes sorry i should have added some values at the end to make it more noticeable sorry

Comment: Should work with my updated solution. Did you try it?